# How to blur background color of body using css?

Tags: css

I have set the background colour to a linear gradient and I want the background colour to be a blur. I have tried a few codes but couldn't make it work.
Here is my code:

```css
body{
    background: linear-gradient(100deg, #3B53D6,#4AFAFA);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 200px; /* Make sure the body is visible */
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

I am learning CSS, please help me! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want the whole page, including all of the text to be blurry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the background separately from the body, i.e. you can use a pseudo element and filter just this pseudo.

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}

body::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(100deg, #3B53D6,#4AFAFA);
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try adding `filter: blur(8px);`, `-webkit-filter: blur(8px);`.

Code:

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(100deg, #3B53D6,#4AFAFA);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* Add the blur effect */
    filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}
```

You may increase the blur by changing `8px` into any number you want.

For example, `10px`:

`filter: blur(10px);`, `-webkit-filter: blur(10px);`.

Learn more in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Comment: This will blur all of the content on the page.

Comment: @disinfor Isn't that what the OP want?

Comment: The question isn't clear enough to tell.

Comment: Thank you,I got the solution!! I wanted the background colour of the body to be blur!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the gradient a pseudo element on the `body` and blur that:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, #3B53D6, #4AFAFA);
  filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    content content content
  </div>
</body>
```

If you add `filter: blur()` to the body, that will blur all of the children as well.